# How to setup SQLite in WebApplicationFactory?

Tags: c#, sqlite, integration-testing, asp.net-core-3.1, in-memory-database

I am writing an integration test for my ASP.NET Core MVC application. The test is about to send a `POST` request to controller and then check if database was updated correctly.

I have a `CustomWebApplicationFactory` where I am trying to configure SQLite in-memory database, but probably I do something wrong.

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    private SqliteConnection Connection;

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        Connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        Connection.Open();

        builder.UseEnvironment("Development");

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            // Unregister existing database service (SQL Server).
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType ==
                    typeof(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>));

            if (descriptor != null) services.Remove(descriptor);

            // Register new database service (SQLite In-Memory)
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Connection));
        });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
public class OrderControllerTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public OrderControllerTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _httpClient = factory.CreateDefaultClient();

        var scopeFactory = factory.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

        using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();

        _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Create_Post_OrderIsCreated()
    {
        // ...
        _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        _context.SaveChanges();
       // ...
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the line `_context.Customers.Add(customer);` triggers the `CustomWebApplicationFactory.Dispose()` method and I get an error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
>
> Object name: 'AppDbContext'.

The error message is very descriptive, but I don't know how to solve it. Why is the database context getting disposed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, the issue is that `_context` is available only in the `_scope`, so I removed `using` and now I have shared database between class tests. Each test have also the option to empty and populate the database.

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
private readonly AppDbContext _context;
private readonly IServiceScope _scope;

public OrderControllerTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
{
    _httpClient = factory.CreateDefaultClient();
    _scope = (factory.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()).CreateScope();
    _context = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    // database is now shared across tests
    _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

Comment: Rather than create the scoped service in the constructor and then access from the test(s) I have been injecting the factory (stored as `private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;`) *then* in the tests I use the factory to create a scope to access a scoped service (such as dbcontext) from within each test. The tests share the database due to the fact that the `WebApplicationFactory` is a class or collection fixture. The constructor in the WebApplicationFactory correctly opens the database connection and only closes it when the `WebApplicationFactory` is disposed.

Comment: @DefinedRisk can you please share an example of your solution?

Answer (score 2):

@Muflix I couldn't add to comment after your comment question as too long so here it is instead...

I'm using xUnit and Shouldly:

> Rather than create the scoped service in the constructor and then access from the test(s) I have been injecting the factory (stored as `private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;`) then in the tests I use the factory to create a scope and access a scoped service (such as `dbcontext`) from within each test. The tests share the database due to the fact that the `WebApplicationFactory` is a *class fixture* or *collection fixture* and this maintains a *single* database connection through its use of the *DatabaseFixture* member (note that this is not strictly being used as a *fixture* here it is simply instantiated as a member of the web application factory, it is so called because it is used elsewhere in my code as a unit testing fixture). The constructor in the `WebApplicationFactory` correctly instantiates the `DatabaseFixture` class which in turn opens the database connection and only closes it when the `WebApplicationFactory` (and therefore the DatabaseFixture) is disposed.

My Test:

```cs
public class MyControllerTests : IClassFixture<MySQLAppFactory<Startup>> // see below for MySQLAppFactory
{
    private readonly MySQLAppFactory<Startup> _factory; // shared for ALL tests in this class (classFixture)

    public MyControllerTests(MySQLAppFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Theory] //example of many tests all of which use SAME _factory instance
    [JsonArrayData("Path-to-Somewhere/MyData.json")] // pass some data
    public async Task Post_should_do_whatever(MyRequest request) // I'm using Shouldly
    {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient(); // create a client form the single instance of webApplicationFactory
        var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync($"api/my", httpContent);

        response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.Whatever);
    }
}
```

The `MySQLAppFactory` creates its own single DatabaseFixture (TestDatabase) during construction (it removes the existing database context from the services and replaces with a context that uses this DatabaseFixture). This same database class persists (the connection is held open) and it is used throughout integration tests. Each time a new context is created is is attached to the same database connection. Its the same base class as used for unit testing (but in the case of unit testing I mostly use a SQLite derived database, rather than MySQL).

```cs
public class MySQLAppFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    private readonly DatabaseFixture _databaseFixture; // THIS factory has THE single Database Fixture instance here

    private bool _disposed;

    public MySQLAppFactory()
    {
        _databaseFixture = new MySQLFixture(); // Create the single instance of MySQL fixture here
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .UseEnvironment("Testing")
            .ConfigureServices(services => //also (as of ASP NET Core 3.0) runs after TStartup.ConfigureServices
            {
                 // remove DbcontextOptions from original API project
                 var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<MyContext>)); services.Remove(descriptor);

                // add the test database context instead
                services.AddScoped<MyContext>(_ => _databaseFixture.GetContext());

                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _databaseFixture?.Dispose();
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _disposed = true;
    }

    ~MySQLAppFactory() => Dispose(false);
}
```

The Fixture (base):

```cs
public abstract class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _seedLock = new object();

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public DbConnection dbConnection { get; protected set; }

    protected abstract bool IsInitialized(bool init = false);

    protected abstract DbContextOptions<IMAppContext> GetBuildOptions();

    // Note that DbContext instances created in this way should be disposed by the 
    // calling code (typically with a using {} block).
    public MyTestContext GetContext(DbTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        var context = new MyTestContext(GetBuildOptions());
        if (transaction != null)
        {
            context.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
        }
        return context;
    }

    protected void Seed()
    {
        // lock and seed here
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {

            if (disposing)
            {
                // dispose managed state (managed objects) that implement IDisposable
                dbConnection?.Dispose();
            }

            // free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            ////if anything exists here then the finalizer is required

            // set large fields to null to help release them faster.

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

}
```

The Fixture (MySQLDerived - as I also use others):

```cs
public sealed class MySQLFixture : DatabaseFixture
{
    private bool _initialised = false;

    private bool _disposed = false;

    private readonly string _connectionString;

    private readonly string _databaseName;

    public MySQLFixture()
    {
        _databaseName = "some name possibly derived from config or guid etc";
        _connectionString = "using _databasename and possibly config, build or environment etc";

        dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
        Seed();
    }

    protected override bool IsInitialized(bool init = false)
    {
        if (!init)
        {
            return _initialised;
        }
        else
        {
            _initialised = init;
            return _initialised;
        }
    }

    protected override DbContextOptions<IMAppContext> GetBuildOptions()
    {
        return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<IMAppContext>().UseMySQL(dbConnection).Options;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // dispose managed state (managed objects) that implement IDisposable
            }

            // free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            ////if anything exists here then the this.finalizer is required below
            dbConnection.Open();
            var command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = $"DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `{_databaseName.ToLower()}`";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // set large fields to null to help release them faster.
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _disposed = true;
    }

    ~MySQLFixture() => Dispose(false);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for that :-)